# Formula to replace 0 with empty cell where F:F used range end

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Using below formula that is working perfectly but it is mentioning extra 0.0 which i do not want.

I just want that where F:F range ends this formula should end too it should work with F:F range.

for Example: F5 has values, formula will give result accordingly otherwise it would be 0
if F6 is empty then formula will also be empty.

I have attached below picture please check.

```
=ArrayFormula(ROUND(IF(LEN(G3:G),IF(F3:F="Confirmed",(13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12,IF(F3:F="Probation",0)))))
```

https://ibb.co/F38hd7Y

same with this it should work with col"E"

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(E3:E="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG,Dec!C3:AG}),,9^9))), " ", )))))))
```

Want to convert this formula into array

```
=IF(A2:A="","",COUNTIF(Jan!C3:AG3,"L")+COUNTIF(Jan!C3:AG3,"H")/2+COUNTIF(Jan!C3:AG3,"S")/4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for the first formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(F1:F),ROUND(IF(LEN(G3:G),IF(F3:F="Confirmed",(13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(G3:G,"mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12,IF(F3:F="Probation",0)))),""))
```

and this should work for the second one:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(E1:E),IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(E3:E="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG,Dec!C3:AG}),,9^9))), " ", )))))),"")
```

Comment: Please have a look at last one, @Marios

Comment: @Learning could you please post that as a different question with more details. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi, @Marios i have applied the 2nd formula which is still not working as i want its not mentioning the 0 till used range.

Comment: @Learning thanks for your comment. Can you post a new question regarding that issue so other readers can benefit from it. Unfortunately stackoverflow does not allow follow up questions. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have posted @Marios please if you look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476854/google-sheet-formula-not-presenting-0-according-to-the-used-range

Comment: @Learning check my answer.