# Google Sheet formula not presenting 0 according to the Used range

Tags: google-sheets

Using below formula that is working perfectly but it is not mentioning 0 where as i highlighted in attached sheet.

I just want that where E:E range ends this formula should end too it should work with E:E range.

for Example: E5 has values, formula will give result accordingly otherwise it would be 0 if E6 is empty then formula will also be empty.

**Original formula:**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/(1/(IF(E3:E="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG,Dec!C3:AG}),,9^9))), " ", )))))))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgVGJxkw39uelgPU9ceZLXflnP8KaFGou4rJfSsfVXc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(E3:E),IF(E3:E="",,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Jan!C3:AG, Feb!C3:AG, Mar!C3:AG, Apr!C3:AG, May!C3:AG, Jun!C3:AG, Jul!C3:AG, Aug!C3:AG, Sep!C3:AG, Oct!C3:AG, Nov!C3:AG,Dec!C3:AG}),,9^9))), " ", ))),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula contains  `1/(1/(…))`. If the value in the `…` is 0, it generates a `#DIV/0!` error. This is catched by `IFERROR` which, in your case, changes it to an empty cell. Removing the `1/(1/(…))` will make the zeros appear. Also, it seems that you can remove the `IFERROR` function as there shouldn’t be any other errors that you want to silent.

### References

- [IFERROR (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for having a look on the sheet, @Martí then there could be any solution to this ?